# Fix Ex4 to Mq4 Issue Easily

Tags: dll, mql4, mql5

[Ex4 to Mq4 Files Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGY8k.jpg)
Fix Ex4 to Mq4 File issues using Converters,some ex4 files are higher build will work too
All forex EA that work on Mt4 can fix their placing order problems easily

This Converter will fix all the issues of ex4 files instantly